# use format string from a property

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

the situation I'm in is following:

I have an interpolated string looking like this:

```
DateTime DateOfSmth;
string PlaceOfSmth;
$"{DateOfSmth}, {PlaceOfSmth}".Trim(' ',',');
```

And a format that should be used on it in:

```
string Format = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}";
```

Now I'd like to use the **format in the property `Format`** in the interpolated string, but I don't know how.

I.E: i'd like something like this to be the result:

```
$"{DateOfSmth:Format}, {PlaceOfSmth}".Trim(' ',',');
```

Could someone help?

Comment: you can do like this Console.WriteLine($"Name = {name}, hours = {hours:hh}") for more detail please visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've already studied it before i posted the question. The real reason i need it like i said is because i need to use the formatting string from the `Format` property. and not write it directly into the string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
string format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
Console.WriteLine($"{DateOfSmth.ToString(format)}");
```

Comment: In the end i used something a little bit similar. Because the format string has content `{0:dd.MM.yyyy}` I could not use your answer directly, but this helped a lot. thanks :)

Comment: just to cflarify - the format string is given and i cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I left the accepted answer to @diiN_. The solution i used is:

```
//this format is given and I can't change it
string Format = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}";
DateTime? Date = DateTime.Today;
string Place = "Washington";

string.Format(Format + ", {1}", Date, Place);
```